# MySQL- combinie two queries

Tags: php, sql, union

I can't solve this problem:

I have mysql DB with many geo-coordinates.

I liked to know which points are within a specific number of miles from specific coordinates AND
Which are within specific square.

Points within a specific area:

```
    (SELECT
        *,
        'area' as type,
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(".$Plat.") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(".$Plng.") ) + sin( radians(".$lat.") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
    FROM
        ".$db."
    HAVING
        distance < ".$radius."
```

points within a specific square:

```
    SELECT
        *,
        'square' as type,
        -1 AS distance

    FROM
        ".$db."
    WHERE
        ((Alat <= ".$Alat." AND ".$Alat." <= Blat) OR (Alat >= ".$Alat." AND ".$Alat." >= Blat)) AND
        ((Alng <= ".$Alng." AND ".$Alng." <= Blng) OR (Alng >= ".$Alng." AND ".$Alng." >= Blng)) 
        ...
```

I use UNION to combine both queries but the thing is "type" and "distance" have different values. So I get the searched point twice. I liked to have every point just once.

But I have no idea how to handle that.

Edit:

For an overview I took just some of the data.

As result I get something like that:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  id  | Alat      | Alng      | distance | type        |
+------+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  42  | 53.704678 | 10.202164 | 12345    | area  
+------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+
|  72  | 23.704678 | 15.202164 | 12345    | area
+------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+
            ......
+------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+
|  42  | 53.704678 | 10.202164 | -1       | square
+------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+
|  81  | 43.778    | 15.201212 | -1       | square
+------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+
            ......
```

- id(72) exists just in the area an not in the square.
- id(81) exists just in the square an not in the area.
- id(42) is in the area and in the square too. So it appears two times. But it only should once. The area should get priority.

but it just should be

```
+------+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  id  | Alat      | Alng      | distance | type        |
+------+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  42  | 53.704678 | 10.202164 | 12345    | area  
+------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+
|  72  | 23.704678 | 15.202164 | 12345    | area
+------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+
            ......
+------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+
|  81  | 43.778    | 15.201212 | -1       | square
+------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+
            ......
```

Comment: Please, provide sample data and your expected result both in a tabular form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GROUP BY after the UNION to remove duplicates.

```
SELECT id, Alat, Alng, distance, type
FROM (
    SELECT *, 'area' as type, ... FROM ...
UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 'square' as type, ... FROM ...
) AS subq
GROUP BY id, Alat, Alng, distance
```

This may not be very efficient with larger result sets, but should work.

Note that this kind of GROUP BY is forbidden in the SQL standard and many other databases (since `type` is not in GROUP BY), but MySQL allows this.